# How to return a record based on parent child relationship

Tags: c#, linq, transitive-closure-table

I have a requirement wherein I need to select Parent Department for a particular position. I have the tables as

```
public partial class Position
{    
 public int PositionId { get; set; }
 public string PositionName { get; set; }
 public int ParentPositionId { get; set; }
}
public partial class DeptPosition
{
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public int DeptId { get; set; }
 public int PosId { get; set; }
}
public partial class Dept
{
 public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
 public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Now here a position can have a parent as another position or a department. Say if Pos1 is having a parent as Pos2 and Pos2 is having a parent as Pos3 and Pos3 is now having a parent as Dept1. So here how do I get the Dept1 which is parent to Pos1 through other positions. Now here if Dept1 is a direct parent to Pos1 then I can find and fix it but how to write a query if a position is having a parent in deparment indirectly.

```
Example:1

Department
DepartmentId       DepartmentName
----------------------------------------------
1                  HR
2                  IT

Position
--------------------------------------------------------
PositionId         PositionName    ParentPositionId
1001               Pos1            1002  //Pos2
1002               Pos2            1003  //Pos3
1003               Pos3            null
1004               Pos4            null

DeptPos
Id                 DeptId          PosId
----------------------------------------
2001               1               1003
2002               2               1004
```

Thanks for all replies.
Now say if I want to get the Parent Department for Pos3. Then I would simply say

```
var parId=db.DeptPos.FirstOfDefault(x=>x.PositionId==id).DeptId;
var parName=db.Department.FirstOfDefault(x=>x.DepartmentId==parId).DepartmentName;

Here id for the position is 1003
```

Now this will give the Parent Department for that position
 And since Pos1 is not having a Department as a direct parent so now I say

```
 Example:2    
Here the id for the position is 1001
var parId=db.DeptPos.FirstOfDefault(x=>x.PositionId==id).DeptId;
Here I get parId as null since Pos1 with Id 1001 doesnot a department as direct parent.
if(parId==null)
{
 var parPosId=db.Positions.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.PositionId==id).ParentPositionId
 //Getting ParentPositionRecord
 var parPosId2=db.Positions.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.PositionId==parPosId).ParentPositionId;
 //Now if there are 20 positions and let's say if that position is having a parent Department via 10 positions. An example here
}
Position
--------------------------------------------------------
PositionId         PositionName    ParentPositionId
1001               Pos1            1002  
1002               Pos2            1003  
1003               Pos3            1004
1004               Pos4            1005
1005               Pos5            1006  
1006               Pos6            1007  
1007               Pos7            1008  
1008               Pos8            1009  
1009               Pos9            1010 
1010               Pos10           null  
----               ----            ------
1020               Pos20           null 

DeptPos
Id                 DeptId          PosId
----------------------------------------
2001               1               1010
2002               2               1020
I need to go on repeating code 10 times or might be ...........
So is there something which gives me DeptId as 1 from DeptPos in above  example by some other way.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what you have tried? Sow some attempted code. Also, show some sample output you're expecting.

Comment: Storing the tree structure in db using a simple parent link might not be the best choice in every situation. As you already have noticed, it makes finding the closest ancestor whose department is defined a bit hard. You might want to store the tree structure in a separate closure table, which will make queries like this easier. For more info: http://dirtsimple.org/2010/11/simplest-way-to-do-tree-based-queries.html

Comment: @RahulSingh plz check the code.